# 14.04.4 to 14.04.5 upgrade: rsyslog script stops working

Tags: scripts, docker, syslog, rsyslog

The docker software (v1.10.2) I run on my Ubuntu 14.04.4 system is configured to save all logs to syslog. To get a specific log file for every docker container, I use the following script:

```
# /etc/rsyslog.d/10-docker.conf
# Log Docker container logs to file per tag
$template DockerLogs, "/var/log/docker/%syslogtag:R,ERE,1,ZERO:.*docker/([^\[]+)--end%.log"
if $programname == 'docker' then -?DockerLogs
& stop
```

Unfortunately, after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04.5, the script stopped working. The docker logs are written to /var/log/syslog and not to the specific log files in /var/log/docker any more.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Robert

Comment: This seems to be no Ubuntu related issue. As I was upgrading Ubuntu, I also upgraded docker to v1.12. Docker is now writing logs no longer with the tag 'docker/<containername>', but only with its containername, which leads to the failure of my script.